# Screen with ssh to overcome disconnection

Tags: bash, ssh

I have a script `name.bash`. I want to run it on the server `serv@domaine` with `ssh` but I'm afraid to run it directly and close my `shell` and stop execution.
I read that i can run my bash on the server with `screen` to overcome these problem. What are the commands I would use please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a modern version of ubuntu on the server, then you can use [byobu](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byobu_%28software%29), which is a more updated version of screen.

From your local:

```
ssh serv@domain
byobu
/path/to/script.whatever
```

Then if your session drops (or you just close the terminal), you can reconnect with the ssh command and be right back where you were.

You can also set byobu to always be running, which is what I do, by typing `byobu-enable`.

Answer (score 1):

If you aren't doing anything interactive in that script, you can just set it to run using `nohup`, which will tell it to continue even if the ssh session ends. this would apply only to the one script rather than screen which essentially keeps your entire login session active.

The command would be:

```
nohup /path/to/name.bash &
```

The final ampersand sets the nohup process to run in the background.

More details on the nohup command:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nohup