# run a time taking task in the server without user logged in dependency

Tags: 14.04, server, scripts, tar

I am using a remote server Ubuntu 14.04 LTS . In my remote server there is a directory `log` which contains multiple files. Total size is 85 GB. I want to make a zip of `log` directory. Command I am using,

```
tar -zcvf log.tar.gz log/
```

It is taking lots of time and my internet is disconnecting sometimes, that's why I have to restart the process every time internet connection disconnects. I connected to the remote server by using SSH. What is the best way to achieve it? I want to run the command once in the server and it should perform the task and finish it even if I am not logged in to server.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Screen with ssh to overcome disconnection](https://askubuntu.com/questions/141706/screen-with-ssh-to-overcome-disconnection)

Comment: I agree with the link here about using `screen` or `byobu`, but maybe consider using a cron job instead that will run at a given time whether you are logged in or not.

Answer (score 0):

In general when logging into a remote system, I recommend using [byobu](http://byobu.co/).  Which is a user-friendly face on tmux/screen.

You can then lose connection to the remote system, and re-attach to running sessions at next login.  Magic!